Movie about boy training for circus carnival act on horse?
I'm looking for a film from the late sixties or early seventies. I thought that the star was Mark Lester. No. I thought that it was the Burt Lancaster Circus film. No.
The scene that I remember most is the boy - he was handsome and blonde like the kid from Oliver. He is training and training to ride the horses in a circus act with ropes tied around his waist and trying to learn the trick. At the end of the movie he is triumphant and is balancing on the horse with no ropes, standing in the saddle, in a glittering (blue?) outfit with tights. It was spectacular... when I saw this as a child.

Toby Tyler, or Ten Weeks with a Circus (1960)

yes!! that is it!! I have to find this film!

Toby Tyler, or Ten Weeks with a Circus (1960)

Taken in by distant members of his family after being orphaned, Toby Tyler runs away to join the circus.


